# Autocomplete city field with yandex suggestView

Tags: javascript, yandex-api

I have an input field for the city. I need a drop-down list of cities to appear when I start entering a city. ONLY CITIES.

```
<input type="text" name="city" id="city">
```

I have a js function, but it shows not only cities, but also regions and the like, but I only need cities

```
function onLoad (ymaps) {
   var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('city');        
}
```

It would also be nice to add an error when pressing a button if the user has not selected anything from the list

Hepl please

Comment: Do you need Yandex API? For Google Maps Places API, you can use `&types=(cities)` to filter only by cities. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete. You get $200 in free credits every month to use on Google Maps API.

Comment: I need only yandex api